# Stop xml.etree from writing special characters as HTML code

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xml, special-characters

In my code I modify some XML and write those to output files. Unfortunately, though, xml.etree converts some special characters to HTML characters, as you can see below. Is there any way to avoid this? If not possible with xml.etree, I am open to other Python XML libraries.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring("<Item a='ë'/>")

print(ET.tostring(xml))
# b'<Item a="&#235;" />'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ElementTree` defaults to US-ASCII encoding. There is no way to represent `ë` in US-ASCII, therefore it falls back to representing the character as an entity, `&#235;`.

The solution is simple:

```
print(ET.tostring(xml, encoding='unicode'))
# => '<Item a="ë" />'
```

**Note** This will give you a `str`, not `bytes`, but omitting the `encoding` parameter gives you bytes, as you can see in your own sample.

To write the XML to file or send it over the network, you need to convert it to bytes. Use a Unicode encoding such as UTF-8:

```
print(ET.tostring(xml, encoding='utf-8'))
# => b'<Item a="\xc3\xab" />'
```

Comment: Thanks! Encodings always confuse me. So to write to a file, you have to open a file handle in "wb" mode, and then you can write the UTF-8 encoded XML to it. I had expected that the file had to be opened in UTF8 mode, too.

Comment: For future readers, when using the `write` method, you can also specify the encoding. So `tree.write(path, encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: @BramVanroy If you write it to a binary file (`open(filename, 'wb')`) then *you* have to do the encoding, i.e. the whole thing expects bytes. If you write to a text file (`open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')`) then Python will do the encoding for you, i.e. the whole thing expects a string. The latter is more convenient when you already have a string.
But what you *really* should use to write an `ElementTree` to file is not `open()`, but [`ElementTree.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

Comment: That actually explains a lot. I always thought that specifying an encoding to a file handle meant that the file handle could only receive pre-existing utf-8 encoded content. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @BramVanroy Since file encodings are an issue, XML has built-in, automatic encoding detection. Parsers will use the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the start of the file to switch to the correct encoding before reading the rest of the file. This is why you never should use raw `open()` calls to read/write XML files. Always use `ElementTree.write()` for writing - this puts the proper encoding into the declaration - and conversely, always use `ElementTree.parse()` for reading - this makes sure the encoding from the XML declaration actually used for reading the file.

Comment: I just checked, and it doesn't seem that the XML declaration is inserted. At least not when using encoding="utf-8". This is not a problem for my case, but I just let you know.

Comment: @BramVanroy That's because UTF-8 is the default for XML files, i.e. when a declaration is missing, UTF-8 is assumed by all parsers. Try `tree = ET.ElementTree(xml)` and `tree.write('filename.xml', encoding='Windows-1252')`. Look at the file with a hex editor to see the difference to an UTF-8 encoded file.